# Can I test chrome extension on jsbin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, google-chrome-extension, jsbin

I have a chrome extension that I installed from local and it working on a localhost html file. I tried transferring the code to a jsbin hosted on a different server but it no longer is working. 
I keep on getting an unknown repsonse from the extension:

```
XYZ Extension API for hlmkhjdabjjpjmcinebgcicmhpjglom: unknown response undefined Object
```

Is it possible to test a chrome extension on JSbin? or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: Edit the answer and add the part of extension code that shows this error. And add a link to jsbin with the entire code you're trying to run.

Comment: This is a private extension (not in app store) with company code so Im not able to do that. I just needed to know whether jsbin allows this or if Im just wasting my time